# How can i make lightning-layout horizontal with nested iterations?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-apps, lightning-layouts

Can someone help me with getting the sections in horizontal format rather than how it is shown in the screenshots? (sorry for the screenshots, i was not able to save the playground file to share)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can just copy-paste the code here, too. Just use the `{}` button to format the code.

Comment: Re: not being able to save the playground app: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/314110/lwc-playground-save-option-removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `<lightning-layout>` and `<lightning-layout-item>`:

```
<lightning-layout multiple-rows>
  <template for:each={transformed}...>
      <lightning-layout-item size="6">
          <lightning-tile ...
```

You can use flex mode if you want to have them all on a single line, or specify a size to wrap around as specified (e.g. 6 results in 2 columns, 4 results in 3 columns).

Comment: That did the trick!! thank you